# How to reset counter in Python

Tags: python, loops

Hi I'm new to programming, i have a program that will count name start from 1 to the range of a data.
My problem is the counter will continue to add the previous name. For example, when i run file 1 , it will show a,b,c , but when i run the second file the name will start from d,e,f. What i want is to reset the counter value to A whenever i choose a new file.

**My code**

```
num = 0
def countname():
    global num
    num += 1
    return str(num)

def change():
  for content in data2:
     filename = "" + "Name" + " " + countname()
     print(filename)
```

Comment: This sounds like a job for `enumerate`, not for a global counter.

Comment: Hi can you explain more on `enumerate`? thanks

Comment: Documentation: [enumerate](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html?highlight=enumerate#enumerate)

Comment: That's mean not the code issues but is my logic problem right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is somewhere else in your code - not in the shown parts - they work:

```
num = 0
def countname():
    global num
    num += 1
    return str(num)

def change(data2):
    for content in data2:  
        filename = "" + "Name" + " " + countname()
        print(filename)

# the content (a,b, etc. is currently ignored)
change ("a b c d e f".split())
```

Output:

```
Name 1  
Name 2
Name 3
Name 4
Name 5
Name 6
```

A better version without global would be:

```
def change_better(data2):
    # start indexing at 1 and loop over index,datapoints
    for index, content in enumerate(data2, 1):
        filename = f"Name {index}"
        print(filename)

change_better ("a b c d e f".split())
```

wich genenerates the same output as above.

Your code is not a [minimal reproduceable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that replicates your problem, the source of your observed error is elsewhere.

My hunch would be that you somewhere add this created filename to some other thing (f.e. *a path*) and you use that to create the file. And there is the problem with repeating names.

See [String formatting: % vs. .format vs. string literal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5082452/string-formatting-vs-format-vs-string-literal) for f-style string literal formatting